# GenericDao extends multiple entities

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, genericdao

Im using GenericDao with few entities and i want to make an a single interface and its implementation with this entities. I have 2 Dao's interface and its implementation that extends GenericDao and i want to combine them into one interface and its implementation.

Something like that:

Entity1Dao:

```
public interface Entity1Dao extends GenericDao<Entity1, String>{

public List<Entity1> getAllFromEntity1();
...
}
```

Entity2Dao:

```
public interface Entity2Dao extends GenericDao<Entity2, String>{

public List<Entity2> getAllFromEntity2();
...
}
```

And i want to combine them and make something like:

```
public interface MultyDao extends GenericDao<*I do not know what needs to be here*>{

public List<Entity1> getAllFromEntity1();

public List<Entity2> getAllFromEntity2();
}
```

and implement it..

Here is GenericDao:

```
package org.dao.nci.person;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
public interface GenericDao<E,K> {
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public String add(List<E> entities) throws Exception;
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public String saveOrUpdate(List<E> entity) throws Exception;
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public String update(E entity, String whereClause) ;
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public String remove(E entity) throws Exception;
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public String removeWhereClause(String whereClause) throws Exception;
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public E find(K key);
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
public List <E> get(String whereClause) throws Exception ;

public String addTest(List<E> entities) throws Exception;

}
```

And ofc i want to use GenericDao's methods for both entities.. )

Is it possible by somehow?

Comment: `extends GenericDao<Entity1>, GenericDao<Entity2>{` why not just make it generic ? How about `getAllFromEntity<T>()` and it should return all entities of type `T`.

Comment: How does GenericDao looks like? Why do you want to combine those two?

Comment: Im using interface and its implementation class in jaxws webservice. So i want to group methods for all entities in one webservice.  I cant find the way how to combine interfaces and its implementations with diferent entities